# Grunt suddenly cant find Less directory

Tags: gruntjs, less

So I've been using Grunt to compile my less files (among other things), and it was working fine, my gruntfile.js is set up correctly, but all of a sudden my terminal is now saying

```
Running "less:components" (less) task
Warning: Cannot find module '/Users/../path/to/directory/../less' Use --force to continue.
```

The less directory is definitely where it should be, so I dont understand why this might be happening.  Any suggestions please?

EDIT: the result of `npm list` shows a long list which looks OK, but does give this error at the end

```
npm ERR! extraneous: grunt-cli@0.1.13 /Users/../path/../node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! missing: nopt@~2.0.0, required by noptify@0.0.3
npm ERR! missing: cwd@^0.3.3, required by resolve-dep@0.4.1
npm ERR! missing: cwd@^0.3.3, required by load-pkg@0.1.0
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The Less configuration in the Gruntfile.js looks like this

```
less: {
      components: {
        files: {         
          'compiled_css/login.css': ['less/login.less'],
          'compiled_css/front.css': ['less/_import.less']          
        }
      },
      options: {
        expand: true,
        paths: [
        'bower_components/bootstrap/less',
        'less'
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: It says `cannot find module`. Post the output of `npm list` (compress the result if its too long) and also your configuration of less task.

Comment: Ive made an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve this.  I deleted the node_modules directory out of the root and ran `npm install` again.

Then ran `grun`t and it all worked.